# How to measure similarities between text (word to word or word to phrase)?

Tags: natural-language-processing, computer-vision

Is there a way to measure to measure similarities between two pieces of text ? Think about the case where you have an image captioning model but you only want to deal/use specific class names. e.g. say you have classes like 'vegetation' , 'car' , etc .. and your captioning model output could be something like 'tree' , 'tree on the side of the road' , 'vehicle' , 'car' ...

Comment: genererate embedding vectors and measure the angle between them (dot product)